# Java-based Config that creates Parameterized Singleton Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I have the following list of bean definitions in XML:

```
<bean id="version201627" class="predicate.ClientVersionPredicate">
    <property name="year" value="2016"/>
    <property name="week" value="27"/>
</bean>

<bean id="version201628" class="predicate.ClientVersionPredicate">
    <property name="year" value="2016"/>
    <property name="week" value="28"/>
</bean>

... // the list goes on
```

Is there a way to convert this to Java-based `@Configuration`, and not creating so many methods?

something like:

```
@Bean
public ClientVersionPredicate somePredicate(String year, String week) {
    return new ClientVersionPredicate(year, week);
}
```

but I can specify the args somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` ([Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html)) and a `BeanDefinitionBuilder`.

```
@Component
public class ClientVersionPredicateDefiner implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) 
            throws BeansException {
        // no need for post processing
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry)
            throws BeansException {
        IntStream.range(27, 47).forEach(week -> {
            String year = "2016";
            BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
                    .genericBeanDefinition(ClientVersionPredicate.class);
            builder.addPropertyValue("year", year);
            builder.addPropertyValue("week", String.valueOf(week));
            registry.registerBeanDefinition("version" + year + week, 
                    builder.getBeanDefinition());
        });
    }

}
```

For this example, I assumed you were needing a version for weeks 27 to 46 in the year 2016. How you define your configuration values is up to you (and depending on your actual configuration needs).

The beans can now be obtained by name:

```
ClientVersionPredicate version201627 = ctx.getBean("version201627");
ClientVersionPredicate version201628 = ctx.getBean("version201628");
...
```

Comment: is there a way to make 1 method instead of 2? I have currently 20 xml bean defs and i would prefer if that come be simplified into 1 method...

Comment: I haven't seen that this is your main point, sorry. Do you really need different bean definitions (each having a unique id) or would a prototype with different initialization values be ok?

Comment: My bad, I just saw you were looking for singletons. :) Bean definition registry postprocessing will be the way to go then..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GenericBeanDefintion` (look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/GenericBeanDefinition.html) for more details) which helps to define & register the beans dynamically.

The following code uses `GenericBeanDefintion` & helps you define the beans which you need through a single method during application start up.

Basically, you need a List of objects (`List<YearAndWeek> yearAndWeeks`) which contain years and weeks or you can use any other collection/array which contain the data & then iterate over it to register the beans with the bean registry.

```
@Component
public class MyProjectSpringUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
           throws BeansException {
           MyProjectSpringUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void addNewBeans() {
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = 
                 applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;

       //Get your years and weeks data here through objects or array
        List<YearAndWeek> yearAndWeeks = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<yearAndWeeks.size();i++) {
             YearAndWeek yearAndWeek = yearAndWeeks.get(i);

             GenericBeanDefinition clientVersionPredicate = 
                                      new GenericBeanDefinition();
             clientVersionPredicate.setBeanClass(ClientVersionPredicate.class);
             clientVersionPredicate.setScope(
                GenericBeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
             MutablePropertyValues props = new MutablePropertyValues();
             props.add("year", yearAndWeeks.getYear());
             props.add("week", yearAndWeeks.getWeek());
             clientVersionPredicate.setPropertyValues();

             //register your bean with id & object
             registry.registerBeanDefinition(
                      "version"+yearAndWeek,getYear()+yearAndWeek,getMonth(), 
                      clientVersionPredicate);
        }
    }
}
```

**YearAndWeek class:**

```
public class YearAndWeek {
    private int year;

    private int week;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an externalized property file to contain the year and week values for your beans.  An example of properties might look like this...

```
version201627.year=2016
version201627.week=27

version201628.year=2016
version201628.week=28
```

Then in your java configuration file, you can do this...

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="version201627")
public ClientVersionPredicate version201627() {
    return new ClientVersionPredicate();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="version201628")
public ClientVersionPredicate version201628() {
    return new ClientVersionPredicate();
}
```